# Is it sinful if we develop a mental image of Allah when we talk about Him?

Tags: halal-haram, allah, image

Islam instructs us not to give image to Allah in order to represent Him.

Usually it's the case that when you you talk about someone or something you develop a mental image of him. Same could happen while talking about Allah. Is that sinful?

If we think about hell, which we haven't seen, we tend to draw a mental image of hell. Does that mean there is no Allah? Or does it mean that Islam is wrong?

Explanation needed.

Comment: islam is never wrong.

Comment: @user689 , we all know that . this place is for solving our questions .

Comment: How does it imply that if we develop a mental image of hell then there is no Allah or that Islam is wrong? Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

It is how our brain functions. We can't think or talk about something without having an image of that (here Allah).

You should try to avoid imagining but if you fail, it's fine and of course not sinful.

Comment: Which mean it's not sinful?

Comment: @BleedingFingers , you have to try to avoid imagining , and if you failed , of course not sinful.

Comment: Please mention that in the answer by [edit]ing it.

Answer (score 1):

This is something you can't change; this is how the brain work. People are more attracted to something they see this is why kaa'ba was built, and this is also why people in the past bowed to idols: they wanted something they could actually see.

Now even if you imagine something when speaking about Allah but you believe that God has no image then this is fine. But if you believe that this is actually God you are seeing then this is sinful.

Comment: Good answer but these are your thoughts and please be careful while giving your own thoughts in shariya' since it's critical matter. I am only saying this so you are not afraid of these sayings when you will be standing on the day of judgement.

So you should back your statements up with Qur'an and Hadith / Sunnah.

*Jazak Allah Khairan. Allah knows best*

Answer (score -2):

Its ABSOLUTELY wrong to make an image of Allah in your brain... Its written in Surah Iklaas Wa lam yakul-lahu kufuwan ahad meaning And there is none like unto Him. So there in nothing in the universe which can be compared to him.. what i would suggest is avoid making an image of Allah in ur brain but if u fail to then...think of pure white light coming from sky as noor or blessings or torch of Allah... you could also make a mental image of the whole universe in ur brain and tell urself i worship the creator of this universe so whenever u think of Allah u think of the creator of the universe... it completely differs from person to person .. some ppl can pray without making a image in their brain... while some do not... As long as u dont make an image of Allah himself in ur brain itz fine...